# How to execute Rake file tasks in parallel

Tags: build, rake, rakefile

I'm using Rake to build a C language build system.
When compiling multiple files,
I want to compile multiple files in parallel, using multiple cores of the CPU.

Can you give me some advice on how to write a Rake file?
I would like to achieve the `make -j` in Rake.

As a restriction, I prefer not to install a new Gem.

For clarity, here is a simplified Rake file.

```
CC = "gcc"

task :default => "hello"

file "hello" => ["hello.o", "message.o"] do
  sh "#{CC} -o hello hello.o message.o"
end

file "hello.o" => "hello.c" do　(1)
  sh "#{CC} -c hello.c"
end

file "message.o" => "message.c" do　(2)
  sh "#{CC} -c message.c"
end
```

For tasks, I can use multitask.
However, for file tasks, I don't know how to describe it.
I would like to run the file tasks (1) and (2) concurrently.

my environment:
*ruby 2.6.4p104 (2019-08-28 revision 67798) [i386-cygwin]*

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create threads and you can run your files in new thread.

For example

```
CC = "gcc"

task :default => "hello"

file "hello" => ["hello.o", "message.o"] do
  Thread.new do
    sh "#{CC} -o hello hello.o message.o"
  end
end

file "hello.o" => "hello.c" do
  Thread.new do
    sh "#{CC} -c hello.c"
  end
end

file "message.o" => "message.c" do
  Thread.new do
    sh "#{CC} -c message.c"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I had missed the basics.
I will try it now.

Comment: After executing "hello.o" and "message.o", "hello" must be executed.
It will result in a link error.
Can I use join or other methods to synchronize them?

If I have a large rakefile, synchronization can be complicated.
Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that rake -m considers all tasks as multitasking. I defined individual tasks only for the tasks that I do not want to be executed in parallel. By specifying something like "rake -m -j 8", I confirmed that the build time was reduced.